# How to change the position of legend in Scatter Chart D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I want to shift the legends on top of the chart

I tried using CSS position relative but seems that it does not work on SVG

please have a look at the codepen

http://codepen.io/7deepakpatil/pen/LkaKoy

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(color.domain())
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
```

above is the code where the legend are being generated.

is it possible using css or please provide any d3 or JS way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Use SVG translate. Similar to what you have but you need to apply it to the whole legend. So I appended a 'g' element, gave it an id for easy selection later and applied a translate before you appended anything to it, like so :

```
var legend = svg.append('g').attr('id','legendContainer')
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(-200,100)"; }) //this is the translate for the legend
  .selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
```

Updated codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqLXRx